# Programmatically scrolling to specific view in CoordinatorLayout, or sticky behaviour

Tags: android, android-xml, android-coordinatorlayout, coordinator-layout

I've got a CoordinatorLayout, and I need to programmatically scroll vertically to have a specific view anchored to the top as a sticky view. The stickiness works by having an AppBarLayout with      `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|snap"` set on the view I want to make sticky. The programmatically scrolling of the CoordinatorLayout is proving to be problematic.

The structure of the CoordinatorLayout content is:

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
 …   
</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

<!--list of reviews-->
<RecyclerView
    ../>


<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    ..
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
   .. />
```

I've tried `scrollTo`, `scrollBy` but can't seem to calculate the correct value for Y. I thought height - view.top would do it but it didn't.

I've tried wrapping in a ScrollView but this caused a RecyclerView in the same layout to disappear, and the smoothScroll didn't work anyway.

I've tried

```
val view = mLayout.findViewById<ConstraintLayout>(R.id.view)
val rect = Rect(0, 0, view.getWidth(), view.getHeight())
view.requestRectangleOnScreen(rect, true) // and tried false
```

I've tried `view.parent.requestChildFocus(view, view)`

--

I'm now trying a new approach, I'm trying to set the views above the one I need to scroll to to View.GONE - which works, except that setting the views above as GONE causes the anchored view to lose its 'stickiness'. I tried adding this view above it but still once I set the above views to `GONE` the stickiness won't work.

```
<View
        android:id="@+id/sticky_helper"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|snap"/>
```

However when I just set the views to `INVISIBLE` the stickiness still works so it seems to be to do with setting them to GONE even though the above view is still visible.

If anyone has a workaround for the stickiness, or indeed knows how to scroll to specific view in CoordinatorLayout I'd be very grateful.

Comment: What layout are you using for `CoordinatorLayout` nested content?

Comment: @MaratZangiev Please see update in my question.

Comment: You want to scroll in `RecyclerView`? Or to any view inside of your `CoordinatorLayout`-s?

Comment: @MaratZangiev Not the `RecyclerView`. I want to scroll to a View that lives inside the AppBarLayout.

Answer (score 2):

Hope, this will help you:

1. scroll your `RecyclerView` to 0 position:

   `recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(0)`
2. Expand your `AppBarLayout`:

   `app_bar.setExpanded(true, true)`

And bacause of I don't know what is inside your `AppBarLayout` can't say how to scroll it in right way :) But your `AppBarLayout` will be expanded and all of it's views will be shown

Comment: Thank you very much, I had already tried similar but didn't give me the exact behaviour I needed. I now have the behaviour I wanted working with a CollapsingToolbarLayout.